# Android mapView availability under graphical layout

Tags: android, android-mapview

I couldn't find any mapview template for the graphical layout.  Mapview is from google, do I have to do something special to bring in the mapview into graphical layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on XML view and write following tag,  : add your map key

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="<MAP KEY>"/>
```

Refer following link for more help

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Thank You,